# Why it takes at most $n$ flops to reduce a matrix a form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-set-theory

[image]

Source: Linear Algebra: Ideas and Applications, Richard C. Penney

I don't know why the author is asking to explain why it takes at most n flops to reduce A with a column containing leading 1 and other entries, not a column containing all zero's. How should I explain the reason for $n$ flops?

Comment: Notice that the dimensions of the matrix are $n$ rows by $n+1$ columns. The asterisks, $*$, are any element. The most important thing to consider is that we want to *only* get a leading $1$ in the first row and that's it. We **do nothing else** to the rest of the matrix. Can you see where the *at most* $n$ flops comes from now?

Comment: Note that we can't just do an operation to a single entry. Each row (hint: or column) operation requires the same number of flops as there are entries in the row [resp: column].

Comment: @pyrazola Since there is leading 1 in the first column, shouldn't it be  not n flops but n-1 flops?

Comment: No. That's the thing: we're not working with the matrix you wrote at the end of the post. We're going to take *any* $ n \times (n + 1)$ matrix $A$, and change it to that matrix with the leading $1$ in the first row. So the first entry of $A$ could be $5$, $2$, or maybe ${1 \over 32768}$. But we want to make it a $1$. If the topleft entry of $A$ is $0$, we'd need to do a row swap, but that doesn't count towards our flop count.

Comment: And take into consideration what @mrstopstraffic pointed out. We can do either row or column operations. There's $n$ rows and $n+1$ columns. For at most $n$, you may use column operations to the first column since there's only at most $n$ entries in the first column.